# Yii2 как правильно организовать поиск по сайту?

Tags: yii2

Всем привет.

Мне надо организовать поиск по сайту как на картинки, имеется две таблицы "profile и profile_has_category".

Первой таблице храниться виде id, область и город специалиста, во второй храниться список выбранных категорий пользователем, там тоже хранится виде id и еще сделано title, как мне правильно реализовать поиск специалистов. Допустим пользователь выбирает автоуслуги и город Москва, как проверять и сравнивать (если так можно выразиться) и выводить всех спецов по городу Москва.
С первым инпутом я разобрался, а вот с городом и регионом я не знаю как быть?

Я взял виджет от картика kartik\typeahead\Typeahead.

Поиск специалистов по категории controller

```
controller`public function actionCategoryList($q = null)
{
$query = new Query();

$query->select('title')
    ->from('profile_has_category')
    ->where('title LIKE "%' . $q . '%"')
    ->orderBy('title');
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
$out = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $out[] = ['value' => $d['title']];
}
echo Json::encode($out);
}
```

view

`Typeahead::widget([
                'name' => 'Search[category]',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Искать специальности ...'],
                'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                'class' => 'search-input-spec',
                'dataset' => [
                    [
                        'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                        'display' => 'value',
                        //'prefetch' => $asset->baseUrl . '/samples/countries.json',
                        'remote' => [
                            'url' => Url::to(['search/category-list']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                            'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);`

БД - profile

```
id        | 1
----------| -
----------| -
----------| -
region_id | 12
city_id   | 465
```

БД - profile_has_category

```
id          | 1
category_id | 1070
title       | Электрик
price       | 100
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не ясна структура вашей БД. Примерно запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  `profile` AS p
JOIN
  `profile_has_regioncity` AS r ON p.id = r.id
JOIN
  `profile_has_category` AS c ON p.id = c.id
WHERE
  r.region_id = "region_id" AND
  r.city_id = "city_id" AND
  c.category_id = "category_id"
```

При его составлении я предположил, что *id* в таблицах `profile_has_regioncity` и `profile_has_category` это *id* пользователя.